# c# WinForms - Во время выполнения кода элементы управления становятся белыми

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня в Shown событии стоит код, но когда форма загрузилась и начинается выполнение кода все элементы становятся белыми, иногда во время выполнения кода они все-же проявляются, но иногда они проявляются не полностью (часть элемента белая). Так вот вопрос, как можно решить эту проблему?

В действии...

[image: Пример.]

Как должно быть...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какого цвета Вы хотите, чтобы они были?

Comment: @Igor мне нужно что бы они были "своего" цвета.

Comment: Вы нам без кода предлагаете гадать что не так в вашем решении?

Comment: @tym32167 Но все же уже догадались. *("Мы гномы, гномы, гномы ...")*

Comment: @tym32167 а смысл от кода будет то? У меня там ничего таким образом с элементами не взаимодействует. Каждый раз когда я использую событие Shown во время выполнения кода элементы становятся белыми (будто бы они не успевают загрузится).

Comment: Обычно принято говорить, что форма "замерзает" или "фризится". У вас длительные операции выполняются в GUI-потоке. Нужно эти операции перенести в отдельный поток.

Comment: Ваше приложение состоит из вашего кода, который работает не так, как вы ожидаете. Вы можете код не приводить, но тогда не удивляйтесь если никто не отгадает, что с вашим кодом не так.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov благодарю, запуск кода в отдельном потоке решило проблему.

Comment: Быстро вы, однако: внесли изменения в код, скомпилировали, проверили. Самая быстрая клавиатура на всём диком интернете...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Обычно принято говорить, что форма "замерзает" или "фризится". У вас длительные операции выполняются в GUI-потоке. Нужно эти операции перенести в отдельный поток. – [Alexander Petrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184217/alexander-petrov)